# xcode-select --install doesn't finish, macOS Sierra running in a VM

Tags: macos, install, xcode

I'm running macOS in a virtual machine and getting errors installing developer tools.

I was trying to install **xcode-select --install**

[image: Video: xcode-select --install does not finish installing] Minute 2, from second 27 until 29.  Check the file **applessdstatistics**...

**Tuesday 9:52 PM**
[image]

**Wednesday 4:12 PM**
[image]

**What I need to install xcode-select (not xcode enterely)?**

Thank you!

EDIT:

Using **Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.12_for_Xcode_8.2.dmg** of *https://developer.apple.com/download/more/* doesn't work properly...

**Wednesday 10:47 PM**
[image]

**Thursday 8:43 AM**
[image]

Comment: Just download Command Line Tools for Xcode from: https://developer.apple.com

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem...

Previosly I had reduced the Memory from **2048MB** to **1536MB**.

I know the minimun requirement is **2048MB**.

I tried creating a new Virtual Machine using **1536MB**, but it was very slowly...

Then I need to restore the memory from **1536MB** to **2048MB**.

Comment: Good catch that running macOS virtualized has lots of pains and problems that may not be apparent at first glance.